# What was the role of the Shadow Proclamation in the Time War?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel, time-war

I have watched only the post 2005 episodes.

The Shadow Proclamation is the highest authority in the entire universe. I mean they are the Police guys and law-keepers.

I had a doubt if any other race has participated in the Time War, but in one of the episodes Sontarans say that they were forbidden to take part.

My question is didn't the Shadow Proclamation intervene in the Time War?

Comment: Your question's not very clear. Could you be a little more descriptive as to what you're looking for?

Comment: i have made it clear @SumanRoy, please check it.

Comment: This is one of those problems that come up in very long running shows like Doctor Who. This came up during a chat session on http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley. Apparently the details regarding Time War and the events surrounding it are mostly part of the new series.Even the Shadow Proclamation was introduced in the new series and not a lot was said about it, at least in the series.

Comment: As such there are many continuity issues around it.  If I had to take a guess, I'd say that the Sontarans were forbidden from fighting because they would fight for the sake of fighting and not to stop the Daleks.

Comment: Oh... Shadow Proclamation was added later!!?

Comment: I'm often in the [chat] if you want to have more free-form discussions of Classic Who's relationship to New Who.

Comment: “The Shadow Proclamation is the highest authority in the entire universe. I mean they are the Police guys and law-keepers.” — source?

Comment: I thought the Church of the Papal Mainframe (or the Church of the Silence, or whatever the hell it is called now) was the greatest authority in the Universe...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

None. The Shadow Proclamation, so far as we can tell, had no role in the Last Great Time War (assuming that's the time war you're referring to; the Last Great was by no means the *only* Time War).

We actually have no indication that the Shadow Proclamation is exceptionally powerful, much less the "highest authority in the universe." It's a strictly galactic organisation that hires *mercenaries* to do its police work. A war between what *have* been stated as the two most powerful societies in the universe is a bit out of their bailiwick.

At any rate, the LGTW took place entirely off-screen except for what little we see in "Day of the Doctor" and there's no indication the Proclamation existed prior to the War, so it's quite probable that the organisation formed in the power vacuum left by the Time Lords' absence.

Comment: The logic behind the formation and existence of Shadow Proclamation makes sense! Thanks :)

Comment: What evidence is there that "it's a strictly galactic organisation"? In "The Stolen Earth" the Doctor just tells Donna they are the "Space Police" without naming a particular jurisdiction, and later in the episode the Shadow Proclamation leader says "The whole universe is in outrage, Doctor" about the stolen planets, and when the Doctor tracks down where the planets were taken, she says she will have to seize the TARDIS because "We are declaring war, Doctor, right across the universe".

Comment: Also, in the context of a sci-fi show why should using mercenaries indicate anything about their level of power? It could be a situation like in the Star Wars prequels where the Republic had paid the Kaminoans to clone an army for them. In real life the weakness of using mercenaries is just that they won't necessarily stay loyal if the going gets tough, but in sci fi you can have various kinds of engineered loyalty.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Among other evidences: the laws the SP enforces are explicitly "Galactic Law," and the Judoon are awful mercenaries to hire as police enforcers representing a peacekeeping force for reasons which should be obvious.

Comment: @BESW - what basis is there for thinking the laws they enforce are "galactic law"? I don't think this was ever stated on the show, the only source mentioned at http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Proclamation is a comic strip from the kid's magazine Doctor Who Adventures, which only an ultra-completist would likely incorporate into their personal canon (and it's not even clear the comic is being used to support the " galactic law" claim as opposed to something else in the opening paragraph, since there's an "additional sources needed" notice attached to that paragraph)

Comment: Also, I think the Judoon would be a fine policekeeping force if the goal is simply to intimidate people into obeying the law, rather than any more humane goal.